# Heap Corruption Detected: after normal block c++ dynamic 2D array

Tags: c++, memory-management, dynamic

I keep getting this error Heap Corruption Detected: after normal block... It only comes up if I try to deallocate memory of my 2D array examScores using delete[]. I used a for loop to delete each array so I'm confused, is there still a memory leak somewhere? I'm not super familiar with memory management so thank you in advance for any help

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;



string getGradeOfExam(double grade, double examAverage) {
    if (grade <= (examAverage - 15)) return "E";
    if (grade >= (examAverage + 15)) {
        return "A";
    }
    if (grade < (examAverage - 5)) return "D";
    if (grade > (examAverage + 5)) return "B";
    return "C";
}

string readNextName(ifstream& inputStream) {
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    inputStream >> firstName;
    inputStream >> lastName;
    string fullName = firstName + " " + lastName;
    return fullName;
}
int readNextExamScore(ifstream& inputStream) {
    int examGrade;
    inputStream >> examGrade;
    return examGrade;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (argc < 3)
    {
        cerr << "Please provide name of input and output files";
        return 1;
    }
    cout << "Input file: " << argv[1] << endl;
    ifstream in(argv[1]);
    if (!in)
    {
        cerr << "Unable to open " << argv[1] << " for input";
        return 2;
    }
    cout << "Output file: " << argv[2] << endl;
    ofstream out(argv[2]);
    if (!out)
    {
        in.close();
        cerr << "Unable to open " << argv[2] << " for output";
        return 3;
    }

    int numStudents = 0;
    int numExams= 0;
    in >> numStudents >> numExams;

    string* studentNames = new string[numStudents];

    //first value corresponds to a specific student, second value corresponds to a specific exam
    int** examScores = new int* [numStudents];
    for (int i = 0; i < numExams; ++i) {
        examScores[i] = new int[numExams];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < numStudents; i++) {
        studentNames[i] = readNextName(in);
        for (int j = 0; j < numExams; j++) {
            examScores[i][j] = readNextExamScore(in);
        }

    }
    //Finds averages of all exams and stores them in an array
    double* examAverages = new double[numExams];
    for (int i = 0; i < numExams; i++) {
        double examAverage = 0.0;
        double totalExamScore = 0.0;
        for (int j = 0; j < numStudents; j++) {
            totalExamScore += examScores[j][i];
        }
        examAverage = totalExamScore / numStudents;
        examAverages[i] = examAverage;
    }

    double totalExamScore = 0.0;
    double totalExamAverage = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numExams; i++) {
        totalExamScore += examAverages[i];
    }
    totalExamAverage = totalExamScore / numExams;

    double* studentAverages = new double[numStudents];

    for (int i = 0; i < numStudents; i++) {
        double studentTotalScore = 0.0;
        for (int j = 0; j < numExams; j++) {
            studentTotalScore += examScores[i][j];
        }
        studentAverages[i] = studentTotalScore / numExams;
    }

    //OUTPUT

    out << "Student Scores:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < numStudents; i++) {
        out << right << setw(6) << studentNames[i] << "\t";
        for (int j = 0; j < numExams; j++) {
            out << examScores[i][j] << "\t";
        }
        out << endl;
    }
    out << endl;

    out << "Exam Averages:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < numExams; i++) {
        out << setw(6) << "Exam " << i + 1 << " average = " << fixed << setprecision(1) << examAverages[i] << endl;
    }
    out << endl;

    out << "Student Exam Grades:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < numStudents; i++) {
        out << right << setw(6) << studentNames[i] << "\t";
        for (int j = 0; j < numExams; j++) {
            out << examScores[i][j] << " ";
            out << "(" << getGradeOfExam(examScores[i][j], examAverages[j]) << ")\t";
        }
        out << endl;
    }
    out << endl;

    out << "Exam Grades:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < numExams; i++) {
        int gradeCount[5] = { 0,0,0,0,0 };
        for (int j = 0; j < numStudents; j++) {
            if (getGradeOfExam(examScores[j][i], examAverages[i]) == "A") {
                gradeCount[0]++;
            }
            else if (getGradeOfExam(examScores[j][i], examAverages[i]) == "B") {
                gradeCount[1]++;
            }
            else if (getGradeOfExam(examScores[j][i], examAverages[i]) == "C") {
                gradeCount[2]++;
            }
            else if (getGradeOfExam(examScores[j][i], examAverages[i]) == "D") {
                gradeCount[3]++;
            }
            else if (getGradeOfExam(examScores[j][i], examAverages[i]) == "E") {
                gradeCount[4]++;
            }
        }
        out << setw(6) << "Exam " << i + 1 << "\t" << fixed << setprecision(1) << examAverages[i] << "\t";
        out << gradeCount[0] << "(A)" << "\t";
        out << gradeCount[1] << "(B)" << "\t";
        out << gradeCount[2] << "(C)" << "\t";
        out << gradeCount[3] << "(D)" << "\t";
        out << gradeCount[4] << "(E)" << endl;
    }
    out << endl;

    out << "Student final grades:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < numStudents; i++) {
        out << studentNames[i] << "\t" << studentAverages[i] << "(" << getGradeOfExam(studentAverages[i], totalExamAverage) << ")" << endl;
    }
    out << "Class Average Score: " << totalExamAverage << endl;

    delete[] studentNames;

    for (int i = 0; i < numStudents; i++)
    {
        delete[] examScores[i];
    }
    delete[] examScores;

    delete[] examAverages;
    delete[] studentAverages;

    return 0;
}
```

My input file contains the following:

```
6 8
Cody Coder  84 100 100 70 100 80 100 65
Harry Houdini  77 68 65 100 96 100 86 100
Harry Potter  100 100 95 91 100 70 71 72
Mad Mulligun  88 96 100 90 93 100 100 100
George Washington  100 72 100 76 82 71 82 98
Abraham Lincoln  93 88 100 100 99 77 76 93
```

Comment: Is there any reason to not use `std::vector` here?

Comment: You also want to steer away from having a bunch of unrelated arrays and instead make a *singular array* of a particular structure.

Comment: @tadman It’s for a class and we’re not supposed to use vectors

Answer (score 2):

This part seems suspicious:

```
    int** examScores = new int* [numStudents];
    for (int i = 0; i < numExams; ++i) {
        examScores[i] = new int[numExams];
    }
```

The array `examScores` has `numStudents` elements, but the upper bound in the for-loop is `numExams`.

Errors of this kind can be often localized using the Valgrind tool. (It worked in this case.) Check it out.

Comment: There's also the part where `delete[]` is called on the top-level array but not on the internal components.

Comment: This answer is correct. The heap is being corrupted due to writing 8 elements, but the size of the dynamically allocated array is only 6 elements. In other words, the array is being written to out of bounds. If you change the loop to `for (int i = 0; i < numStudents; ++i) {`, then it will only write 6 elements and the heap corruption message will no longer appear.

Comment: Just to clarify: The mistake that the OP made was that he wrote "numExams" instead of "numStudents" in the condition expression of the `for` loop.